# Add Checkbox In Magento 2 Admin Form

Tags: magento2, admin, adminform

I have a custom module, it has two fields, `table_name` and `table_number` and I have added new field like `is_reserve` to check if table is reserved,

I have added column in table with integer data type, now I need to add **a checkbox** for this field **on admin form**:

```
$fieldset->addField(
                 'is_reserved',
                 'checkbox',
                 array(
                     'name' => 'is_reserved',
                     'label' => __('is reserved'),
                     'title' => __('is reserved'),
                     'onclick'   => 'this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;',
                     /*'required' => true,*/
                 )
             );
```

I have added this in block file, what else I need to do to get my checkbox working? It will be a great help if someone can give any hint about this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look: **vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/Newsletter.php**:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'subscription',
            'checkbox',
            [
                'label' => __('Subscribed to Newsletter'),
                'name' => 'subscription',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'onchange' => 'this.value = this.checked;'
            ]
        );
```

We can follow the same logic.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply, I have added like this, checkbox appeared, but it does not save the value in field. any hint?

Comment: Try to get the param in your controller? for example: `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`. Need to check the value is in the params.

Comment: nope, I am not able to get values of that field in controller.

Comment: All fields are not in the controller?

Comment: I cant understand, i am new to magento, can you please explain?

Comment: Try to vardump the controller: `$this->getRequest()->getParams()`? Is there any values?

Comment: yes, it gives null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50844/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-anand).